Selecting Maximum Subset of Points with Increased Minimum Distance Constraint
I'm working on a spatial analysis problem in Python where I have an unordered list of 2D point coordinates. Each point represents a city, and all cities are guaranteed to have a minimum distance of 10 km from each other. My objective is to find the largest subset of these cities such that every city in the subset has a minimum distance of 20 km from every other city in the subset.
Here's the core of my challenge:

Initial constraint: Every city is at least 10 km away from every other city.
New constraint for the subset: Every city must be at least 20 km away from every other city in the subset.

The distance between any two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2)  is calculated using the standard Euclidean distance formula. Given the potentially large number of points, I'm looking for an efficient algorithm or approach in Python to solve this problem.
I've considered a greedy approach where I iteratively pick a city and exclude all cities within 20 km of it. However, I'm concerned this might not yield the largest possible subset due to the nature of the greedy selection.
Does anyone have suggestions on algorithms or methods that could efficiently find the maximum subset of points meeting the 20 km minimum distance constraint?
Any insights or pointers would be greatly appreciated!

This is the maximum clique problem. Cities are nodes, and each pair of nodes gets an edge IFF they meet the distance constraint. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_problem. Finding maximal cliques is easy, but finding the maximum clique is hard.

This is the maximum clique problem. Cities are nodes, and each pair of nodes gets an edge IFF they meet the distance constraint.
From Wikipedia, the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm may help. It finds all maximal cliques, including the maximum.
Here's the Bron-Kerbosch algorithm for finding all maximal cliques in an undirected graph.
Initialize R & X to be empty sets, and P to be the vertex set of the graph.
algorithm BronKerbosch2(R, P, X) is
    if P and X are both empty then
        report R as a maximal clique
    choose a pivot vertex u in P ⋃ X
    for each vertex v in P \ N(u) do
        BronKerbosch2(R ⋃ {v}, P ⋂ N(v), X ⋂ N(v))
        P := P \ {v}
        X := X ⋃ {v}

Efficiency: O(3^(n/3))
